# Aligning different parts of an equation with certain spots in the line above

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to get certain parts in the second line of an equation to line up with certain parts in the first line.  For example,

```
X=AAA+BBB+CCC

 = a + b + c
```

where here I am wanting the lower-case letter to line up in the middle of its three upper-case counterparts and all of the operators to align.  I have tried using `align` in the following way:

```
\begin{align}

  X&=A&AA &+ B&BB &+ C&CC \\

  &= &a &+ &b &+ &c

\end{align}
```

This results in horrible spacing. I have also tried using `tabular`, but the spacing is bad there also.  I would like the first line to be written as it would be normally and then the second line to line up as desired.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `alignat` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{6}
  X&={}& A&AA  &{}+{}& B&B&B &{}+{}& C&C&C \\
   &={}&  &a   &{}+{}&  &b&  &{}+{}&  &c&
\end{alignat}
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that the `align` environment uses a `rcl` alignment for each of the components. That's why your output seems to be bunched together in "mini-equations".

Here are a couple of options, using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) or not:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cmathbox}[2][x]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{$#1$}%
  \makebox[\@tempdima][c]{$#2$}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Original using \verb|align*|:
\begin{align*}
  X&=A&AA &+ B&BB &+ C&CC \\
  &= &a &+ &b &+ &c
\end{align*}

Using \verb|alignat*|:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  X&=AAA &&+ BBB &&+ CCC \\
  &=\cmathbox[AAA]{a} &&+ \cmathbox[BBB]{b} &&+ \cmathbox[CCC]{c}
\end{alignat*}

Using \verb|array|:
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{{}\mathrel{=}{}}c*{2}{@{{}\mathbin{+}{}}c}}
    X & AAA & BBB & CCC \\[\jot]
      &  a  &  b  &  c
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

My `alignat` solution differs slightly from @IanThompson's. His would be more general if you don't want to horizontally centre the expression components. The `array` solution mimics the behaviour via correct spacing around the operators (relational and binary), as well as vertically between expressions (using `\jot` which is `3pt`).

Answer (score 3):

I often resort to using `\makebox[<size>]{<new text>}` which uses a box as wide as `<size}` to place the `<new text>`.

To compute the `<size>` I use `\withdof{<old text>}` form the `calc` package.  By default this will center the `<new text>`, but you can also specify the alignment with `[l]` for left, `[r]` for right, or `[c]` for center.  In the second example below I left aligned the `a` and `b`, and right aligned the `c` for illustrative purposes (not suggesting that that looks good).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  X &= AAA + BBB + CCC \\
    &= \makebox[\widthof{$AAA$}]{$a$}   
     + \makebox[\widthof{$BBB$}]{$b$}   
     + \makebox[\widthof{$CCC$}]{$c$}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  X &= AAA + BBB + CCC \\
    &= \makebox[\widthof{$AAA$}][l]{$a$}   
     + \makebox[\widthof{$BBB$}][l]{$b$}   
     + \makebox[\widthof{$CCC$}][r]{$c$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```