# How to split and align equations when they are inside an enumerate environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, vertical-alignment, align, itemize

How to make the first line of aligned equations sit in the same baseline as the bullet and make the equation left justified?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $3!=3\times2\times1=6$
    \item $\tfrac{5!}{3!}=\tfrac{5\times4\times3!}{3!}=5\times4=20$
    \item \begin{align*}
                    \frac{n!}{(n-2)!}   &=\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)!}{(n-2)!}\\
                                                        &=n\times(n-1)\\
                                                        &=n^2-n
                \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the `aligned` environment works just fine, with the `[t]` option to get the bullet on the first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $3!=3\times2\times1=6$
    \item $\tfrac{5!}{3!}=\tfrac{5\times4\times3!}{3!}=5\times4=20$    
    \item $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
                    \frac{n!}{(n-2)!}   &=\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)!}{(n-2)!}\\
                                                        &=n\times(n-1)\\
                                                        &=n^2-n
                \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

**edit:** added a negative thin space `\!` just before the `aligned` block to
counteract the thin space `\,` built into the beginning of `aligned`.
for some background, see the question [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the “`aligned`” environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482/579).

Comment: I think you need to insert `\!` between `$` and `\begin{aligned}` to remove the unnecessary white space.

Comment: @Ohmyghost: Thanks for the good question. I just had a minor related question. Suppose in addition to what you desire in the problem, one also would like to make sure the equal signs appearing first in each bullet point are vertically aligned, how can we go about this please? (in other words inter-bullet alignment, so to speak)

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I don't understand. Sorry. Please show me the sample by your handwriting.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora -- you could use `\widthof` on the pre-equal-sign parts of the first two as described in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45574/579).  you'd have to flush those parts to the right in the box with `\hfil`, otherwise they'd be centered in the box.

Comment: That's elegant, barbara!. @Ohmyghost, just the vertical alignment of = signs of equations in two different bullet points above. Thanks both.

Comment: very helpful dear Barbara. Thx