# Aligned Equations With Itemized Number

Tags: align, itemize, enumitem

I have been trying to make the aligned equations in the same line with item number. I have tried `array`, `aligned`, `alignat`, and `eqnarray`, but they dont work out for me.

The picture is from `align*` environment which I resort to do.

Thanks in advance, genius!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess [How to split and align equations when they are inside an enumerate environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68231) answers your question?

Comment: Thanks! I did put [t] once but other errors distracted me....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

For this you need to enclose `aligned[t]` environment in text line math.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   bla bla
\item\hfil$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{6+8+x}{4} & = 8\\
                  x & = 4\times 8 - 6 -8 - 10\\
                  x & = 8
            \end{aligned}$
\item bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Similar questions was already asked here, so it it is worth to search through SE for alternative answers.