# Align environment without newline

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, align, environments

Is it possible to use the `align` environment while suppressing the auto `\newline`?

I have a problem with the following command:

```
\begin{lemma}  
   \begin{align*}  
a+b &= c \\\   
&=d  
   \end{align*}  
\end{lemma}
```

I want the first equation `a+b=c` to be on the same line as **Lemma** but instead TeXstudio put it on the next line. I tried using `aligned` enviroment instead but it gave funny result.

Could anyone please suggest me how to fix the problem?

Comment: You probably want `aligned` with the `[t]` optional argument ( `$\begin{aligned}[t] a&=b \\ c &= d \end{aligned}$`), or to write the lemma differently.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Would you mind writing it up as a full answer so I could accept it? I believe it might benefit people who have the same problem as me a lot.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that equivalent questions have been asked before, so I'll see if I can find a duplicate first.

Comment: While the context is a bit different (list instead of lemma), I think this one is fine: [How to split and align equations when they are inside an enumerate environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68231)