# Enumerate with extra line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, line-breaking, enumerate, line-spacing

I'm using math mode,

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item
\begin{align*}
3(2x+4)-4x &= 6-x &\text{Initial equation (1)}\\
6x + 12 - 4x &= 6-x &\text{Distribute (2)}\\
6x-4x+x &= 6-12 &\text{Rearrange (3)}\\
3x &= -6 &\text{Combine Like Terms (4)}\\
x &= \boxed{-2} &\text{Simplify (5)}
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}
```

When I type this up, I get this:[image]

Why is there a giant blank link between "1." and the first line? How can I remove that line?

Thank you!

Comment: The usual method is to use `aligned`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68231 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394

Comment: @Eric Lee Maybe because of the fact that you are provoking a new environment to enter an equation, which, by itself goes to the next line to deliver a  number (suppressed) equation.