# Using arrays to align parallel equations: Why isn't $|z|$ centered?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, arrays

There was an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45568/aligning-different-parts-of-an-equation-with-certain-spots-in-the-line-above) about aligning different parts of two parallel equations in a multiple line environment, and I'm trying to adapt Werner's answer that used an array for my own use. Probably the problem is that I don't fully understand the code I should put directly after `\begin{array}`. Here are my code and the output:

```
\[
  \begin{array}{c*{2}{@{{}\mathrel{<}{}}l}}
    1 & |z| & |k|\inv \\[\jot]
    |k| & |\phi(z)| & \hphantom{|} 1
  \end{array}
\]
```

[image: output]

Why isn't the `|z|` in the top of the array centered? How should I fix that? (I also welcome comments about other aspects of the code, if applicable.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you wanted to write

```
*{2}{c@{{}\mathrel{<}{}}}l
```

instead of

```
c*{2}{@{{}\mathrel{<}{}}l}
```

which means having the last two columns left-aligned.

In fact, the syntax for multiple columns with same alignment is

```
*{<number of columns>}{<column alignment>}
```

Also, since the `<` symbol is defined as `\mathrel` by default, you can eliminate it:

```
*{2}{c@{{}<{}}}l
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{*{2}{c@{{}<{}}}l}
    1 & |z| & |k|\inv \\[\jot]
    |k| & |\phi(z)| & \hphantom{|} 1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover note that (citing egreg's comment) "adding a new column without intercolumn space for the exponent and changing the third one to be centered, avoids guessing that the width of `k` is the same as the width of `1`".

That is, the same result can be obtained with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{*{2}{c@{{}<{}}}c@{}l}
    1 & |z| & |k| & \inv \\[\jot]
    |k| & |\phi(z)| & 1 &
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a new column without intercolumn space for the exponent and changing the third one to be centered avoids guessing that the width of *k* is the same as the width of 1.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\inv{^{-1}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c*{2}{@{{}\mathrel{<}{}}c}}
    1 & |z| & |k|\inv \\[\jot]
    |k| & |\phi(z)| & \hphantom{|} 1
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

in your original code `c*{2}{@{{}\mathrel{<}{}}l}` means first column is center and the two last column are left

[image]