# Center fractions in equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, alignment

I am trying to create to create a set of equations as follows

[image]

The fractions `1/2` and `40/89` should be dead centered above each other,
similarly for `1/2` and `49/89`. And `0.040` and `0.036` should be right above each other.
Ideally the operators `\cdot`, `0` and `=` should also be right above each other.
Is this possible without some dirty hacks as depicted below?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\spc{\hspace*{0.087cm}}
\def\spct{\hspace*{0.075cm}}
\begin{align*}
       \widehat{p}_a 
    &= \spc \frac{1}{2} \spc \cdot \frac{X}{10} + \spc \frac{1}{2} \spc \cdot \frac{\,Y}{10}
     = \spct \frac{1}{25} \spct 
     = 0.040 \\ 
       \widehat{p}_g 
    &= \frac{40}{89} \cdot \frac{X}{10} + \frac{49}{89} \cdot \frac{\,Y}{10} 
     = \frac{16}{445} 
       \approx 0.036
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `align` isn't set up to treat parallel equations this way; this question covers the same situation: [Using arrays to align parallel equations: Why isn't $|z|$ centered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a job for an `array`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{c *{6}{ >{{}}c<{{}} >{\displaystyle}c } }
\widehat{p}_a 
    &=& \frac{1}{2}  &\cdot& \frac{X}{10} &+& \frac{1}{2} &\cdot& \frac{\,Y}{10}
    &=& \frac{1}{25}
    &=& 0.040 \\[2ex]
\widehat{p}_g 
    &=& \frac{40}{89} &\cdot& \frac{X}{10} &+& \frac{49}{89} &\cdot& \frac{\,Y}{10} 
    &=& \frac{16}{445} 
    &\approx& 0.036
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there any typographical reason one should avoid doing this in practice?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I see no reason to reject it; on the other hand, using the natural width might better show the differences. Try and pick the one that seems clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This can alternately be done as a TABstack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{32pt}% BASELINE SKIP OF ROWS
\Matrixstack{
\widehat{p}_a 
    &=& \frac{1}{2}  &\cdot& \frac{X}{10} &+& \frac{1}{2} &\cdot& \frac{\,Y}{10}
    &=& \frac{1}{25}
    &=& 0.040 \\
\widehat{p}_g 
    &=& \frac{40}{89} &\cdot& \frac{X}{10} &+& \frac{49}{89} &\cdot& \frac{\,Y}{10} 
    &=& \frac{16}{445} 
    &\approx& 0.036
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]