# How use the align environment to do this

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm trying write this two equations
[image]

but I only get this: [image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}anglosajones
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings} 

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
Y_{1t}& + \beta_{12}Y_{2t}& + \gamma_{11} &+ \gamma_{12}X_{2t}& &+ \gamma_{14}X_{4t} = \mu_{1t}\\ \beta_{21}Y_{1t}& + Y_{2t}& + \gamma_{21} & &+ \gamma_{23}X_{3t} &+ \gamma_{24}X_{4t} = \mu_{2t}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Any one can help me, please? I wanna reduce the space between the terms.
I few a lot of time trying and I do not get it

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the missing minimal code, starting with `\documentclass{ `, finishing with `\end{document} `. Makes it easier for all of us, as many times answers depend on your preamble.

Comment: This is a situation where `array` is usually a more easily controlled alternative than `align` (or even `alignat`).  Some suggestions are given in answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45568

Answer (score 4):

You could get away with `alignat`, but it's simpler with `array`. Anyway, I'll show both methods

With `array` I define 15 columns, right aligned ones alternate with centered ones with empty atoms at either end for the operation or relation symbols.

For `alignat*` the syntax is similar, but there are a few subtle points to consider.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% let TeX use the right spacing
\begin{array}{
  r
  *{7}{>{{}}c<{{}}r}
}
Y_{1t} &+& \beta_{12}Y_{2t} &+& \gamma_{11} &+& \gamma_{12}X_{2t} && &+& \gamma_{14}X_{4t} &=& \mu_{1t}
\\[1ex]
\beta_{21}Y_{1t} &+& Y_{2t} &+& \gamma_{21} && &+& \gamma_{23}X_{3t} &+& \gamma_{24}X_{4t} &=& \mu_{2t}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}


\begin{alignat*}{7}
Y_{1t} &+{}& \beta_{12}Y_{2t} &+{}& \gamma_{11} &+{}& \gamma_{12}X_{2t} && &+{}& \gamma_{14}X_{4t} &= \mu_{1t}
\\
\beta_{21}Y_{1t} &+{}& Y_{2t} &+{}& \gamma_{21} && &+{}& \gamma_{23}X_{3t} &+{}& \gamma_{24}X_{4t} &= \mu_{2t}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, I was getting crazy. Thanks a lot

Comment: In the question, the `_2t` and `_3t` are in different columns.  (pedantic noodge.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah, right!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah, I notice but I could add the empty space with an extra &. Now I have a new problem... who add two diferrent referrer, one for each equation... Meaby I will use the alignat enviroment because I don't get it with array

Comment: @Walras I fixed the alignment with both methods; if you need equation numbers, use `alignat` (no `*`).

Comment: @egreg Yes, I do that with alignat because I couldn't do with array. Thanks you a lot! You saved me

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `alignat*`. Note it is not necessary to load `amsmath`when you load `mathtools` , since the latter does it for you.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{layouts}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{listings}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{5}
    Y_{1t}& + \beta_{12}Y_{2t} & & + \gamma_{11} & & + \gamma_{12}X_{2t}& & &{} + \gamma_{14}X_{4t} & = \mu_{1t}\\
    \beta_{21}Y_{1t} &+ Y_{2t}& & + \gamma_{21} & & & & +\gamma_{23}X_{3t} &{}+ \gamma_{24}X_{4t} & = \mu_{2t}
    \end{alignat*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]